# Adapative card not rendering properly - No renderer for this attachment

Tags: node.js, botframework, adaptive-cards

When i see the adaptive card JSON in adapative designer it is working fine, when checking in BOT emulator it is displayed fine, but after i publish the code in BOT present in ASE environment getting this error. [ For all adapative card ] Don't really know what is the problem ?
i am using Adapative card v 1.0
[image]

Comment: Can you please update your question with the full card JSON? I'll start doing some testing, but there have been cases in the past where some of the JSON properties need to be lowercased (like `weight` and `size`)--if you use Designer, you can usually see a yellow squiggly line underneath them showing it's a schema warning

Comment: Also 1.0 is heavily outdated....

Comment: But same card json, is working fine in Bot emulator and other instance of BOT applicaiton, as i tested the same @mdrichardson,

Comment: Yes, @TimCadenbach it is bit outdated, but still this should not be a issue in displaying.

Comment: I don't know, just guessing but the Bot Emulator already uses a newer version. Its not guaranted that if you try a card in Bot emulator it works in 1.0. Best try it on https://www.adaptivecards.io/designer and see if it works there. Or use https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=madewithcardsio.adaptivecardsstudiobeta which is afaik completely backwards compatible.

Comment: @VinodkumarG Please update your question with your full card JSON.

Answer (score 1):

After raising the issue, with Microsoft , we found the root cause of the issue, it is because the webchat.js used, if we use the minimium it doesn,t support Adapative Card, it took a lot a time to find out.

when we use minimal bundle, which doesn't include Adaptive Cards. we need to use the full bundle if you want to use Adaptive Cards,

```
//Use this --
    <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
    //Not this script 
    <script crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat-minimal.js"></script>
```

doc referral - https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/01.getting-started/a.full-bundle

https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat#integrate-with-javascript